# NSArray of doubles iOS (Objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

In my array I have this data, each value is type double:

```
(
    "28.04234",
    "29.3234",
    "25.03324",
    "9.390000000000001",
)
```

And I need to change all elements to NSString only with 2 decimal how can I do this with the best approach optimizing code.

For example:

```
myArray[0] = "28.04"
myArray[1] = "29.32"
```

....

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter`

Comment: `let a = yourArray.map {
    String(($0 * 100).rounded() / 100)
}`

Comment: Based on what you show as your array, it looks like you're dealing with JSON, and the data is coming in as an array of strings that contain floating point values? Can you edit your question to show more info about the source of your data and it's format?

Comment: @AMayes The question clearly specifies Objective-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift you could do this with a map statement. In Objective-C you must have an NSArray of NSNumbers. It's not possible to have an `NSArray` of a value type like double in Objective-C. (It *is* possible - normal, even -  to have a C array of floating point values, but I don't think that's what you're talking about.)

Try code like this:

```
NSArray <NSString *>*mapArrayOfNumbers(NSArray <NSNumber *> *sourceArray) {
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: sourceArray.count];
    for (NSNumber *aNumber in sourceArray) {
        [result addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.02f", aNumber.doubleValue]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

And you could call it like this:

```
NSArray <NSNumber *> *numbers = @[@(1.1), @(2.2), @(3.4567), @(8.901234), @(9.876543)];
NSArray <NSString *> *strings = mapArrayOfNumbers(numbers);
for (NSString *aString in strings) {
    NSLog(@"Entry = %@", aString);
}
```